# How to "Hlookup an array" with a formula

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to perform a `sumproduct` function on two arrays. I'd like to find a way of asking excel to select the first array if the column match a certain value.

In my simplified case if the value is "`1`" pick the first array and perform `sumproduct` with the array below A ...something that prevent me from spending the day nesting if (obviously a formula like =SUMPRODUCT(IF(O4=1;F4:F8;IF(O4=2;G4:G8;IF(O4=3;H4:H8;IF(O4=4;I4:I8))));L4:L8) works but in my real case is no use)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((O4=$F$4:$I$4)*$F$4:$I$8*$L$4:$L$8)
```